# Can Intune be used to decrypt TLS/SSL web traffic on my managed Mac?

Tags: mac-osx, certificate, microsoft-intune

I'm curious to know how much of my personal activities I can run thru my new workplace managed Mac.

[image]

I notice Intune installed a number of certificates and keys. Is this effectively MitM for all my HTTPS web traffic? How do I know what can be decrypted and what is safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intune, as a product, does not have capability to decrypt a traffic.
This is a feature of a proxy server.
The certificate installed by Intune is used to authenticate your device to Intune and Azure AD.

That being said, your workplace administrators could use Intune to install some software and/or configure your Mac to send traffic to a proxy server and decrypt it there. This is done by a third-party security product, but not Intune itself.

Comment: this is good to know

Answer (score -1):

> I'm curious to know how much of my personal activities I should run
> thru my new workplace managed Mac.

None. Keep your work and personal business separate.

Comment: i edited the post for clarity. the part you quoted isn't my question